# Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am getting the following response from the Facebook Ad Library API

`{"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: \u003CAPI_VERSION>","type":"OAuthException","code":803,"fbtrace_id":"AXZ00I_mwgTvJwqIImb1SBw"}}`

Below is the CURL I am trying to execute;

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/ads_archive');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "search_terms='california'&ad_type=POLITICAL_AND_ISSUE_ADS&ad_reached_countries=['US']&access_token=330479468051422|t_w8UDcd2QYqQ_hfxfs-LsKSxIA");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

echo $result; 

?>
```

Is there anything you can see that I have done wrong, much apprecaited thankyou.

Comment: It should not be `<API_VERSION>`. You should replace that with the API version you are using.

Comment: how do i find the api version?

Comment: @WizKid i think its 8.0 do you know is that the value i should replace it with